# FTP error, cannot access a server, but other can

Tags: wordpress, ftp, server, parallax

Yesterday i accessed the server of a friend, and all went good.
But today I'm getting this error message(on filezilla).

```
Status: Connecting to 37.187.32.6:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Error:  GnuTLS error -12: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 37.187.32.6:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 ProFTPD 1.3.4c Server (ProFTPD) [37.187.32.6]
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 AUTH TLS successful
Status: Initializing TLS...
Error:  GnuTLS error -12: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

And with FireFTP, I see this

[image: this is what i see when I try to acces the server with fireftp]

And this is in the index.html file

```
Welcome to Parallels!

If you are seeing this message, the website for is not available at this time.
If you are the owner of this website, one of the following things may be occurring:

You have not put any content on your website.
Your provider has suspended this page.

Please login to https://:8443 to receive instructions on setting up your website
New to Parallels?

Parallels is a worldwide leader in virtualization and automation software that optimizes computing for consumers, businesses, and Cloud services providers across all major hardware, operating systems, and virtualization platforms.

For the Cloud, Parallels automation and virtualization software enables cloud services providers to rapidly and profitably deliver the widest range of cloud services that small businesses want and need. Our software includes key building blocks of cloud service delivery - self service control panels, billing, cloud service provisioning and virtualization. We enable the delivery of all types of services that small businesses need - shared web hosting and web applications, messaging and collaboration services, virtualized infrastructure services and thousands of other applications.

Our Automation products allow businesses to optimize their systems to maximize profit. Our Virtualization products allow personal computers to run several operating systems on one computer (like OSX and Windows) and for individual servers to function like many servers at once for creating cloud computing environments.

This website was created using our Parallels Panel product. We offer a full line of Billing, Sitebuilder and cloud computing tools. Please visit www.parallels.com to find out more information.
Test pages

Parallels Plesk Panel provides several test pages that you can use for checking the scripting features, testing database connections and mail sending. Click an icon to see test pages for different scripts:

FastCGI
Python
PHP
Perl
SSI

Consumer Products
Parallels® Desktop
for Mac
Parallels® Desktop for Mac The best solution for running Windows, Linux, or any of many other operating systems alongside OS X.
Parallels® Desktop for
Windows and Linux
Parallels® Desktop for Windows and Linux Simultaneously run multiple operating systems on your PC
Service Provider Products
Parallels® Automation
Parallels® Automation Hosting, SaaS, and cloud computing automation solution.
Parallels® Panel
Parallels® Panel The Best Control Panel Ever For Easy, Complete and        Profitable      Hosting
```

The strange thing is that my friend and others can access the server.
Has anyone faced this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to File -> Site Manager -> Transfer Settings and choose active or passive mode. It should resolve your problem.

Comment: Where should I do this "File -> Site Manager -> Transfer Settings" ?

Comment: Oh brohter, File option is available in nav menu on top. :(